# Moving jsp pages to Angular 7

Tags: java, angular, jsp, spring-rest

I am currently working on an angular project to update our existing applicaiotn from jsp to angular 7. However, there are some jsp pages that i cant yet convert completly to html because they need legacy support.

So i need to know how to move them to angular. My idea is to copy the jsp pages and all the css it has to angular component.

```
The jsp code is something like below
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/cwf/common/include.jsp"%>
<link
    href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/static/css/insurance/insureServ.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<%-- START CONTAINER --%>
<div id="container">

    <%-- START HEADER --%>
    <div id="header">

        <div class="headerLogoProd">&nbsp;</div>
        <%-- ///Use  class="headerLogoPSE" or class="headerLogoProd" depending on desired logo /// --%>
        <div class="floatleft">
            Welcome,
            <c:out default="Guest" value="${name}" />
        </div>
        <div
            style="border-style: none; float: left; font-size: 1.5em; font-family: sans-serif; color: #FF800D">PRODUCTION</div>
        <div class="floatright">
            <a target="_blank"
                href="http://test.net">Contact
                Us</a> | <a href="mailto:insurance@tst.net">Feedback</a> | <a
                target="_blank" href="http://fakeurl.net">ABDHome</a>
        </div>

    <%-- START Icon Elements --%>
        <c:forEach items="${userTamRoles}" var="userTamRole">
            <c:if test="${userTamRole eq 'ATH'}">
                <div class="icon_element"
                    onMouseOver="this.className='icon_elementHover'"
                    onMouseOut="this.className='icon_element'">
                    <a target="_blank" href="fake.do"><img
                        src="static/images/ins/asdf.gif" alt=""
                        width="90" height="70" vspace="5" align="left"><br />
                        <h3>Inquiry</h3> View transactions for the
                         Transfer Service.</a>
                </div>
            </c:if>
///More html code similar to above here


</div>
<%-- END CONTAINER --%>
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.href;
var n = url.indexOf("https://pott");
if(n > -1) {
    document.getElementById("ddd").style.display = "none";
    } 
</script>
```

now the current code which uses spring has the webserivce as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/inland", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView insuranceLandingpage(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    // get the user name and set it in the session, we will use this in the jsp
    String name = cuoUser.getUserFirstName() + " " + cuoUser.getUserLastName();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("name", name);

    // get entitled products /Roles from TAM
    List<String> user= this.headerUtil.getRolesFromReqHeader(request, userId);
    request.setAttribute("userTamRoles", user);
    return new ModelAndView(".abc.portal.insurance");
}
```

and the servlet.xml has the mapping defined

```
**

<definition name=".abc.portal.insurance"
        template="/WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/insurance/inlanding.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="body"
            value="/WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/insurance/inlanding.jsp" />
```

**

now with angular i cannot use model and view so i will have to refactor the webservice to return a json object. However, how can i render the jsp page? i can copy the entire jsp page and paste it into a component in angular. but how do i render the request parameters?E.g, how can i render this 
`<c:forEach items="${userTamRoles}" var="userTamRole"> or <c:out default="Guest" value="${name}" />` into in the angular componenet? will it recognize this as jsp syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue myself. instead of re rendering the jsp page on angular, i just added a view resolver in my servlet xml file.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</value>
    </property>
    </bean>
        <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-tiles.xml</value>
                    <!-- <value>/WEB-INF/config/cwf/tiles-defs-cwf.xml</value> -->
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```